# Как мне исполнить n идентичных циклов?

Tags: java

Как мне исполнить n идентичных циклов?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public void someFors(int howMany)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) 
    {
        for(int u = 0; u < howMany; u++) 
        {
            System.out.println("WTF?!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Плюс за телепатию.

Comment: Минус - за стимулирование новичков задавать идиотические вопросы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну, вопрос не идеален, но, судя по галочке, ТС можно, всё же, понять, хоть формулировка и не очень. Я бы, конечно, иначе бы сформулировал. Что-то типа "Как мне исполнить n идентичных циклов?". Так что буду считать, что ваш минус не совсем справедлив в виду трудности формулирования "правильного" вопроса для новичков.